# Access Violation in wpfgfx_v0400.dll?

Tags: wpf, c++-cli, c++-cx

I'm using WPF controls to draw images as video.

The summary code is below:

```
while(true)
{
    mStream = gcnew UnmanagedMemoryStream((unsigned char*)jpegBuff, jpegBuffLenght);
    JpegBitmapDecoder^ decoder = gcnew JpegBitmapDecoder(mStream, BitmapCreateOptions::PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption::Default);
    bitmapSource = decoder->Frames[0];
    myWPFControl.DrawImage(bitmapSource)
}
```

But sometimes, it is crashed with the message "Access Violation", the call stack is below:

[image]

I don't know how to fix it.

```
UPDATE:
```

Each while(true) loop is a thread that requests video stream from IP Camera and draw it on WPF control.

This issue usually occurs when there are more 3 cameras connected.

And rarely occurs when there are less than 3 camreas connected.

Please help me.

Many thanks,

T&T

Comment: The `while(true)` part confuses me. Can you add up a bit more of a context?

Comment: By context I mean more of the associated code actually, e.g. what is `jpegBuff` and where it comes from, same for `bitmapSource` and other variables defined outside.

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but have you tried the enum `BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad` ? Also, does the `UnmanagedMemoryStream` last longer than the raw pointer? If so there might be a problem.